# Analytical evaluation of double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int^a_{-a}\int^a_{-a}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{4a^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y,$$
where $a> 0$.

Mathematica gives the following answer:

$$ \frac{a}{3} (\sqrt{2} + \sinh^{-1}(1)).$$

This goes well beyond my basic calculus 101 training.
Is anybody able to give me a step-by-step analytical solution?

Regards

Comment: I improved your terminology and typesetting; see my edits to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Exploiting the even symmetry and making use of

$$\int \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x^2}{2} \log(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+C$$

evaluation of the inner integral yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^a \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{4a^2}\,dx\,dy &= \frac1{a^2} \int_0^a \int_0^a \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy \\\\
&=\frac1{a^2}\int_0^a\left(\frac a2\sqrt{a^2+y^2}+\frac{a^2}{2} \log(a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2})-\frac{a^2}{2}\log(y)\right) \,dy
\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Use integration by parts for the middle term in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$

---

> **EDIT:**
>
> **The OP has requested to see a presentation on evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_0^a \log(a+\sqrt{y^2+a^2})\,dy$ by integration of parts. To that end, we proceed.**

Let $u=\log(a+\sqrt{y^2+a^2})$ and $v=y$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^a \log(a+\sqrt{y^2+a^2})\,dy&=a\log(a(1+\sqrt{2}))-\int_0^a \frac{y^2}{a+\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}\,dy\\\\
&=a\log(a(1+\sqrt{2}))-\int_0^a \frac{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}\,dy\\\\
&=a\log(a(1+\sqrt{2}))-a+a\int_0^a \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}\,dy\\\\
&=a\log(a(1+\sqrt{2}))-a+a\log(a(1+\sqrt{2}))-a\log(a)\\\\
&=a(\log(a)-1+2\log(1+\sqrt{2}))
\end{align}$$

Comment: I tried to complete this solution:

$\frac{1}{a^2} \int^a_0 (\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{a^2+y^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\log(a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2})-\frac{a^2}{2}\log{y})dy\\
= \frac{1}{2a} \int^a_0 (\sqrt{a^2+y^2}+a\log(a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2})-a\log{y})dy\\$

Comment: I split it up in three parts:
first part:
$\int^a_0 \sqrt{a^2+y^2} dy \\
= \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{a^2+a^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\log(a+\sqrt{a^2+a^2})-\frac{a^2}{2}\log a\\
= \frac{\sqrt{2}a^2}{2} + \frac{a^2}{2} \log (a+\sqrt{2}a) - \frac{a^2}{2} \log (a)\\
= \frac{\sqrt{2}a^2}{2} + \frac{a^2}{2} \log (1 + \sqrt{2})\\
= \frac{a^2}{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sinh^{-1}(1))$

Comment: Second part: I wasn't able to solve it with integration by parts.
Mathematica gave me the following answer:
$\int^a_0 a \log(a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}) dy = a^2 (\log (a) - 1 + 2 \sinh^{-1}(1))$

Comment: Third part: 
$\int^a_0 - a \log y dy = - a \int^a_0 \log(y) dy\\
= - a^2 (\log (a) - 1))$

Comment: Adding all three:
$\frac{1}{2a} (\frac{a^2}{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sinh^{-1}(1)) + a^2 (\log (a) - 1 + 2 \sinh^{-1}(1)) - a^2 (\log (a) - 1)))\\
= \frac{a}{4} (\sqrt{2}+5 \sinh^{-1}(1)$

Comment: Question 1: where did I go wrong?

Comment: Question 2: how do I solve the second part with integration by parts?

Comment: @user44136 I've edited to present the integration by parts development.  Note that $\text{arsinh}(1)=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Your answer is great, it helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Pleased to hear.  You're very welcome.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Use polar coordinates (I obtain it by dividing each quarter of the square along the diagonal starting at the origin and noticing that the integral of the considered function is the same when calculated on each of these two domains) :
$$I=\int^a_0\int^a_0 \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{4a^2} \,dx \, dy=\frac{2}{4a^2} \int^{\frac\pi4}_0 \int^{a\sec \theta}_0 r^2 \, dr \, d\theta$$
So by symmetry :
$$\int^a_{-a} \int^a_{-a}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{4a^2} \, dx \, dy = 4I = \frac2{a^2} \int^{\frac\pi4}_0\int^{a\sec \theta}_0 r^2 \, dr \, d\theta \\
$$$$= \frac2{a^2}\int^{\frac\pi4}_0 \frac{a^3}3\sec^3\theta \, d\theta = \frac {2a} 3 \int^{\frac\pi4}_0 \sec^3\theta \, d\theta\\
$$$$=\frac {2a}3\left[\frac{\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)+\ln(\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)}{2}\right]_0^{\frac\pi4}\\=\frac{a}{3} (\sqrt{2} + \sinh^{-1}(1)).$$

Comment: yes, sorry, forgot the $r d\theta$, already cancelled.

Comment: Two questions one the polar transformation
(1) how do you go from $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to $r^2$, shouldn't this be just $r$?
(2) How do you determine the integral boundaries after the polar transformation? I found the following boundaries: $[0,\pi/3]$ for $\theta$ and $[0,a]$ for $r$

Comment: Indeed the square root only gives r but $dxdy=rdrd\theta$ for the boundaries you can try to draw the quarter of the square but you have necesserely a dependence of $r$ in term of $\theta$. The boundaries you founs is one sixth of a circle since r is constant

Comment: I followed the solution for $\int^{\pi/4}_0 \sec^3 \theta d\theta$ from this website: https://www.cymath.com/answer.php?q=integrate%20sec%5E3(x)

Comment: $\frac{sec(\theta)tan(\theta)+ln(sec(\theta)+tan(\theta)}{2}$ for $\theta = \pi/4$ gives $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{2}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{2}+sinh^{-1}(1)}{2}$

Comment: Making the final solution $\frac{a}{6}(\sqrt{2}+sinh^{-1}(1))$. Which is half of the right answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{\left.\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}{\root{x^{2} + y^{2}} \over 4a^{2}}
> \,\dd x\,\dd y\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0} =
> a\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\root{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}$

With $\ds{\vec{r} = x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y}}$, note that in $\ds{2}$D:
\begin{align}
r & = {1 \over 3}\nabla\cdot\pars{r\vec{r}\,} =
{1 \over 3}
\bracks{\partiald{\pars{rx}}{x} - \partiald{\pars{-ry}}{y}} =
{1 \over 3}\,\bracks{\nabla \times \pars{-ry\,\hat{x} + rx\,\hat{y}\,}}_{\ z}
\end{align}

> With the Stokes Theorem:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\root{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
{1 \over 3}\oint_{\mrm{square}}\pars{-ry\,\hat{x} + rx\,\hat{y}\,}\cdot\dd\vec{r}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\bracks{
\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 + y^{2}} \times 1\,\dd y +
\int_{1}^{0}\pars{-\root{x^{2} + 1} \times 1}\,\dd x} =
{2 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{\root{2} + \,\mrm{arcsinh}\pars{1} \over 3}}
\end{align}

> The integral is evaluated with the change of variables
>   $\ds{x = \sinh\pars{\theta}}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{\mrm{arcsinh\pars{1}}}\cosh^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta =
\int_{0}^{\mrm{arcsinh\pars{1}}}{1 + \cosh\pars{2\theta} \over 2}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{arcsinh}\pars{1} +
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\sinh\pars{\theta}
\root{1 + \sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}}_{\ 0}^{\ \,\mrm{arcsin}\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\,\mrm{arcsinh}\pars{1} + \root{2} \over 2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac 1 {4a^2} \int^a_{-a}\int^a_{-a} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy = \text{what?}
$$

$$
\int_{-a}^a (\text{an even function}) = 2\times\int_0^a (\text{the same function}), \text{ so}
$$
\begin{align}
& \int_{-a}^a \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \  dx = 2\int_0^a \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\  dx = 2\int_0^{\arctan a} \sqrt{y^2\tan^2\theta + y^2} (\sec^2\theta\,d\theta) \\[10pt]
= {} & 2|y| \int_0^{\arctan a} \Big(\sec\theta\Big) (\sec^2\theta\,d\theta) = 2|y| \int_0^{\arctan a} \sec^3\theta\,d\theta.
\end{align}

This is one of the more challenging among freshman-level integrals. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed) tells us how to find that
$$
\int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta = \frac 1 2 \sec\theta\tan\theta + \frac 1 2 \log|\sec\theta+\tan\theta| + C.
$$
So we need
$$
\left[ \frac 1 2 \sec\theta\tan\theta + \frac 1 2 \log|\sec\theta+\tan\theta| \right]_0^{\arctan\theta}.
$$
From trigonometry we have
\begin{align}
\tan\arctan a & = a, \\[10pt]
\sec\arctan a & = \sqrt{1+a^2}.
\end{align}

Maybe you can do the rest. (?)